# What is the percentage of students required atleast equal to?

Tags: probability

If atleast 90 percent students are good at sports, atleast 80 percent students are good at music and atleast 70 percent students are good at studies, then the percentage of students who are good in all three is atleast equal to?

My approach: I couldn't quite proceed in the the proper way, however my answer came as 50 percent.

Answer (score 0):

I assume independency. Then the probability that a student is good
at all three is at least $$\frac{9}{10}\times\frac{8}{10}\times\frac{7}{10}=50.4\%$$

If there is no independency then the information is not enough to solve
this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is 40%.

Let's depict the situation with a "table"

G is good, N is not good.

```
Sport   NGGGGGGGGG
Music   GNNGGGGGGG
Studies GGGNNNGGGG
```

This configuration, in which incapabilities do not overlap, gives the minimum number of good-at-everything student.

As you can see the answer is:

```
    100% - ((100%-90%)+(100%-80%)+(100%-70%)) = 40%
```

Hope this helps

Comment: $$P(ABC)=1-P(\overline{ABC})=1-P(\overline A)-P(\overline B)-P(\overline C)=1-\frac1{10}-\frac2{10}-\frac3{10}$$